# Shortest path calculation from shapefile data using GeoTools?

Tags: geotools, shortest-path

I'm using geotools 14.3 with swing to load two shape files. A road network and a node network (road junctions).

Objective

I want to calculate the shortest path from each node to every other node. I've used python with QGIS to successfully do this. But now I want to achieve this programatically using GeoTools. I've been following [this](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide.old/extension/graph/index.html) tutorial.

I've followed up to graph building, now I want to calculate shortest path. But it's a bit unclear for me on selecting nodes.

```
//find a source node (usually your user chooses one)
Node start = ..
```

How could I select a node from my point shapefile?